# How to set asp:DynamicField width

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I tried to set the width of my dynamic field inside gridview like the below

```
<asp:DynamicField DataField="Latitude" HeaderText="Latitude" 
                  HeaderStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-Width="100px" 
                  FooterStyle-Width="100px">
</asp:DynamicField>
```

It found no change with the code. Somebody can help me on how to do this

Comment: Rather than giving Width in pixels, try giving it in percentage.
HeaderStyle-Width="40%"